# Django queryset - get latest results in **ascending** order

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Django, if I want to get the latest 10 instances of my model in DESCENDING order, I can do this:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by(‘-the_field_I_want_to_order_by’)[:10]
```

But how do I get the latest 10 instances in ASCENDING order?  I know I can reorder them in memory after pulling them from the DB:

```
reversed(MyModel.objects.order_by(‘-the_field_I_want_to_order_by’)[:10])
```

but I was curious if there is a way to do it just with a query set.

Using 2 queries, I guess I could do something like:

```
count = MyModel.objects.count()
MyModel.objects.order_by(‘the_field_I_want_to_order_by’)[count-10:]
```

but it would be nice to get it all with one query, if possible.

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, I'm not saying that the above techniques are too slow, or unacceptable, or need to be avoided. The purpose of this question was just to find out what is/isn't available, via the QuerySet API, in regards to the getting the latest X results in ascending order.

Comment: It's too late here for me to work it out but I think the `.reverse()` queryset method could help. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#reverse).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is exactly the kind of access about which the `reverse()` docs say "Django doesn’t support that mode of access (slicing from the end), because it’s not possible to do it efficiently in SQL."

Comment: @Daniel - I tried that, but it just un-does the '-' in my original example and then returns the *first* 10 objects (i.e. it acts like I put the .reverse() BEFORE the [:10]).  Kinda odd...

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper - If that's the case, then maybe you should put your comment as an answer instead of as a comment, so it can be marked as the accepted answer (if no one else comes up with a different one).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use slice notation for this, as normal:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('-the_field_I_want_to_order_by')[:10][::-1]
```

The reason for this is that the last slice doesn't get translated into SQL -- it forces the QuerySet to evaluate and turns it into a list. (This also means it doesn't require an extra query.)

```
>>> type(MyModel.objects.order_by('-the_field_I_want_to_order_by')[:10])
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
>>> type(MyModel.objects.order_by('-the_field_I_want_to_order_by')[:10][::-1])
<type 'list'>
```

Tested in Django 1.5 on Python 2.7.

You can also use your second method with only one query using a similar strategy (force evaluation to list):

```
list(MyModel.objects.order_by('the_field_I_want_to_order_by'))[-10:]
```

This way is less efficient, though, since it forces the creation of a list the same size as `MyModel.objects.all()`.

Comment: Using `[::-1]` is equivalent to using `reversed`, as the OP discusses but is hoping to avoid. Both reverse the result set in memory. Either one is probably the best way to handle this, so I don't say this to be critical.

Comment: True. I forgot about the original use of `reversed` after reading the discussion of `queryset.reverse()` in the comments. But yes, this is the way to go. There's no negative indexes supported in slicing querysets because, as the Django docs say, the translation to SQL ends up being really ugly (and not always possible).

Comment: As a side note, even if the database does it for you, it's still getting reversed "in memory", so I'm not sure what the trade-off is there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's input.  A couple of people posted the answer as comments, but not as an answer...  So here it is in answer form for easier visibility later:

It appears that the answer is **NO, you cannot get the latest X results in ascending order with a single QuerySet**, as slicing from the end is not supported by Django.  The results either need to be reordered in memory:

```
reversed(MyModel.objects.order_by(‘-the_field_I_want_to_order_by’)[:10])

# or, reorder in memory using the technique suggested by Two-Bit Alchemist:
MyModel.objects.order_by('-the_field_I_want_to_order_by')[:10][::-1]
```

or you need to hit the DB twice (or somehow magically know how many items will be in your query set):

```
qs = MyModel.objects.order_by(‘the_field_I_want_to_order_by’)
count = qs.count()
MyModel.objects.order_by(‘the_field_I_want_to_order_by’)[count-10:]
```

Unless you are retrieving a TON of items from the database, the former technique would probably be not only more concise, but more efficient.